# Using Case for dynamic selection of columns in stored procedure in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

[SQL Fiddle with the table schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0576f/33/0)

I was following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294943/using-dynamically-selecting-columns-of-mysql-stored-procedure) to create a stored procedure for dynamic selection of columns. I was wondering if there is any solution to select more than one field in the `more` condition. I'm getting syntax error when aliasing a column name and putting multiple columns in the `more` condition and I have read that my following attempt is not possible in MySQL. I want to know if there is any working statement to the effect of

```
      CASE choose_field
           WHEN 'one' THEN COUNT(*) AS Count
           WHEN 'more' THEN n.id,pmu.name sender,pm.message, m.modify_id,ps.submit_id
      END
```

Here's the complete command that works when only one field is specified in each condition without using alias:

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE notification(IN choose_field varchar(4),IN user varchar(10))
BEGIN
    SELECT
      CASE choose_field
           WHEN 'one' THEN COUNT(*)
           WHEN 'more' THEN n.modification_id
      END
    FROM
      `notification` n
    LEFT JOIN user_modification m ON (n.modification_id = m.modification_id)
    LEFT JOIN pm ON (n.pm_id = pm.pm_id)
    LEFT JOIN users pmu ON (pm.recipent_id = pmu.user_id)
    LEFT JOIN users pmus ON (pm.sender_id = pmus.user_id)
    LEFT JOIN users pmm ON (m.user_id = pmm.user_id)
    WHERE
    (pmu.name = user OR 
     pmm.name = user) AND
    n.is_read = 0;
 END//
```

Then I call the procedure with  `Call notification('one','Peter')`

Table Schema

```
CREATE TABLE notification
    (`id` int, `modification_id` int,`pm_id` int,`is_read` int)
;

INSERT INTO notification
    (`id`,`modification_id`,`pm_id`,`is_read`)
VALUES
    (1,1,NULL,0),
    (2,NULL,1,0),
    (3,2,NULL,0)
;

CREATE TABLE user_modification
    (`modification_id` int, `user_id` int,`page_id` int, `is_approved` int)
;

INSERT INTO user_modification
    (`modification_id`,`user_id`,`page_id`,`is_approved`)
VALUES
    (1,1,5,1),
    (2,2,2,1),
    (3,3,3,0)

;

CREATE TABLE pm
    (`pm_id` int, `sender_id` int,`recipent_id` int,`msg` varchar(200))
;

INSERT INTO pm
    (`pm_id`,`sender_id`,`recipent_id`,`msg`)
VALUES
    (1,1,2,'Hello');

CREATE TABLE users
    (`user_id` int, `name`varchar(20))
;

INSERT INTO users
    (`user_id`,`name`)
VALUES
    (1,'Tom'),
    (2,'Peter'),
    (3,'David')
;
```

Comment: Just to clarify...if you give the script a 'one' then you want the count(*) to be the field you are selecting...otherwise you want modification_id returned?  And you want more than just one field (modification_id, other_id,etc...) returned when you put in more?

Comment: you cannot select it like that.. basically you are saying give me a bunch of columns in one column.. the case is populating one column.. so you have to duplicate the case for each column..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it to something like this

```
DELIMITER//
CREATE PROCEDURE notification(IN choose_field varchar(4),IN user varchar(10))
BEGIN
    IF choose_field = 'one' THEN
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
          `notification` n
        LEFT JOIN user_modification m ON (n.modification_id = m.modification_id)
        LEFT JOIN pm ON (n.pm_id = pm.pm_id)
        LEFT JOIN users pmu ON (pm.recipent_id = pmu.user_id)
        LEFT JOIN users pmus ON (pm.sender_id = pmus.user_id)
        LEFT JOIN users pmm ON (m.user_id = pmm.user_id)
        WHERE
        (pmu.name = user OR 
         pmm.name = user) AND
        n.is_read = 0;
    ELSE -- # -- could also be -- ELSEIF choose_field = 'more'
        SELECT
            n.id,pmu.name sender,pm.message, m.modify_id,ps.submit_id
        FROM
          `notification` n
        LEFT JOIN user_modification m ON (n.modification_id = m.modification_id)
        LEFT JOIN pm ON (n.pm_id = pm.pm_id)
        LEFT JOIN users pmu ON (pm.recipent_id = pmu.user_id)
        LEFT JOIN users pmus ON (pm.sender_id = pmus.user_id)
        LEFT JOIN users pmm ON (m.user_id = pmm.user_id)
        WHERE
        (pmu.name = user OR 
         pmm.name = user) AND
        n.is_read = 0;
    END IF;

 END//
```

basically just use the if inside of your stored procedure to do the check for your query and run one or the other query... you could do this with setting user - defined variables equal to the part you want to select and concat it to a query as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do more in one statement than what you should be / want to be.  A couple solutions:

- Dynamic SQL can handle this...use the stored procedure to build a sql statement then execute the variable.  Not sure if I'd recommend this though
- Create an if statement that reads the variable and runs one of two select statements depending on what it is
- Create 2 additional stored procs, one for count and one for 'more'.  Use the main stored proc to evaulate if statments (one / more) and run the correct storedproc.

One statement to return different number of columns is a bit difficult.